# It is possible to add a button to a Select Field in sencha touch 2

Tags: sencha-touch

Ext.field.Select by default comes with the buttons: "Done" and "Cancel", but I need to add a third button in the middle, an "Add" button, that allows the user to insert a new option if what he needs is not in the options.

Is there a way to do this in Sencha Touch?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible. First of all, see these two documentation pages [toolbar](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.4/2.4.2-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.picker.Picker-cfg-toolbar), [defaultPhonePickerConfig](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.4/2.4.2-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.field.Select-cfg-defaultPhonePickerConfig) to learn how to add custom buttons to picker toolbar.

As an example:

```
{
    "xtype": "selectfield",
    // also there is defaultTablePickerConfig
    "defaultPhonePickerConfig": {
         "toolbar": [
             {
                 xtype: 'button',
                 text: 'Add',
                 align: 'left',
                 handler: function(){}
             }
         ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much. I cound't open the links, seems broken. But thanks!!